# Error when trying to install mysql server in ubuntu server 12.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

I try to reinstall mysql server in my ubuntu 12.04 LTS server and I get always the same error.

Configuring mysql-server-5.5

Unable to set password for the MySQL "root" user

An error occurred while setting the password for the MySQL administrative user. This may have happened because the account already has a password, or because of a communication problem with the MySQL server.
                                                                                                                                                                                  You should check the account's password after the package installation.
                                                                                                                          Please read the /usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.5/README.Debian file for more information.

PLEASE FIND ATTACHED the screen shot in the link:

[screenshot](http://send.hr1.gr/2014.08.24_15.16.16_error.jpg)

I searched a lot in all forums for similar cases and I followed all recommended commands without success.

Does anybody have an idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a permissions error, try completely removing and then reinstalling

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server

sudo apt-get install mysql-server && apt-get upgrade
```

Here is the documentation for mysql on ubuntu [LINK](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/mysql.html)

Comment: Doesn't help. I removed and installed mysql 20 times. I get always the same error!!!